# how to extract android linearlayout to another xml file?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout

I have a long android layout xml.

how can I extract a linearlayout in it to another file?

how is the including convention?

I'm using eclipse

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on you xml layout then >> `Extract Include..`

you able to Extract layout and automatically include in parent layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

add this to ur another file under layout..

```
 <include layout="@layout/urfirstlayout"/>
```

Reference:
[Check this link for more info](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use < include > tag:[Re-using Layouts with include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html
Basically if you save your layout in titlebar.xml
Include it like this: `<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>`